# InputConnectionController missing while using zefyr package in Flutter 1.20

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-test

Today, I upgraded my Flutter SDK to LTS 1.20 from 1.17. After, the installation; the app is not running and showing error.

[image: error after running flutter run]

[image: complete error track]

How can I resolve the issue?  I can't continue working on my app, please help.

Answer (score 1):

There was a breaking change on TextInputClient https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/add-currentAutofillScope-to-TextInputClient

The Zefyr package has had some changes merged and it looks like `currentAutofillScope` may have been addressed.
https://github.com/memspace/zefyr/pull/379/commits/41c1b9383df1fe480f20fb4a8d6bdc378084aa8b

You should try pointing your pub directly at master and see if it resolves your issue. Something like:

```
zefyr:
  git:
      url: https://github.com/memspace/zefyr
      ref: master
```